# Native libraries are included in the AAR, but not installed

Tags: android

I have a dependency (SDK) that is given to me in the AAR format. It works with their sample app, but when I copied the AAR file to my own app, it doesn't work. The log says the .so files are missing.

I built a standalone APK file and the .so files are there, but when installed on the device/emulator, the .so files are not copied to the `lib/arm64` folder, which is the case for their sample app.

There is nothing special on their `build.gradle.kts` related to the library, other than just

```kotlin
dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that in modern APK files the .so files are no longer extracted when installing the APK (so checking for the extracted .so files is not a good indicator). Instead they are directly used from within the APK where they are stored uncompressed and aligned to 4K boundaries so that they can be directly mapped to RAM. You should better check the APK file(s) if they contain the .so files.

Comment: Hi @Robert, thank you so much for your answer. The problem is that I got an error log showing that the Java side is directly trying to read the .so files/load the library `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/app/~~KPBuC8PxOmDEHIkuOafQsA==/.../.so`. I guess in this case the SDK is doing something funky and I might have to look into include the .so as resources or something like that?